# Has there been any information released about Albrecht's Character in Diablo?

Tags: character-identification, diablo

Albrecht is one of the main characters in the Diablo Series, but only because he was Diablo's First Vessel in the games. Outside of this, there is really only mentions of him, and unfortunately, this doesn't really tell us much about who he was.

All we *do* know is:

1. He was Son of Leoric and Brother of Aidan
2. He was kidnapped by Lazarus and became Diablo's First Vessel
3. He seemed to be enjoying himself in his new home (Tristram)

Is there any additional (canon) lore or information about who Albrecht was as a person? I think there was maybe a reference about his above average intelligence, but there is little else I am currently aware of.

Comment: Albrecht accompanied his family when they came to Tristram, from where Leoric would govern Khanduras. Leoric noted that Albrecht appeared to enjoy his new home.

As the Darkening of Tristram progressed, Diablo attempted to claim the king's body, but was not strong enough to fully take possession. The demon required a host, simple and innocent, and thus found Albrecht to be fitting.     Albrecht is the only known host for any Prime Evil to transform into human form and/or remain alive (even for a few moments) after the defeat of the possessing demon.

https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Albrecht

Comment: @llanyort thanks for the comment. Fristly, this is an answer, not really a comment. Secondly, unfortunately this is exactly the information I am referring to in my question. I am looking for information beyond this, about the character himself, not just his involvement in the storyline.